# Issue with Scanner class

Tags: java, groovy, dsl, java.util.scanner, basic

I am using Groovy to build a DSL that will handle BASIC scripts.

I have a line like this:

```
100 INPUT V
```

Which is picked up by a regex which injects some code into the script being executed:

```
    def retString = "scan = new Scanner(System.in);"
    retString += "${matcher[0][1]} ="
    retString += "scan.nextLine()\n"
    return retString
```

This code is duly executed but never returns (i.e. the Scanner never returns from nextLine() and so a value for V/matcher[0][1] is not returned, instead the code is stuck waiting for keyboard input no matter how many times I hit the enter key.)

What have I vote wrong here? The input is echoed in a TextArea as it is being typed (i.e. this is the focus at the time) - is it related to that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end this appears to be one of those (rare) areas where BASIC has more expressive power than Java or Groovy - to solve this I had to alter the windowing code (adding a JTextField to accept input), write an ActionListener and implement some latching. Not particularly difficult but about 25 lines of code in comparison to BASIC's 1.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is a typo in the question or a real error, but you have:

```
retString + "${matcher[0][1]} ="
```

Shouldn't it be this?

```
retString += "${matcher[0][1]} ="
```

But, that's probably not affecting your lack of return.  I'm guessing that the problem is that the input stream of the text area is not System.in.  You should check to see what stream is being used and creating a new scanner around that stream instead of System.in.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, but sadly was just a typo. I'll have a look at the input stream issue.